# Why my index page is shown at google search engin?

Tags: apache, unix, search-engine

Hi deae the problem is this, here is my website URL http://pkbazaar.com When I search my site at google search-engin, the google search-engin showns index page as a Heading, and dates, apache etc. as contents.. Like this..
,,

**Index of**
http://pkbazaar.com/
Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8m DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at pkbazaar.com ...

the question is this Why google not shows my originol contents and headings that I used in my website. anybody help me please........

Comment: It had probably been indexed by Google earlier, when your website wasn't on yet. Your content will be updated as soon as Google comes back on your website.

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question. Voting to move this to related site http://webmasters.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should tell the Google Bots to crawl your website again.

I suggest you to create a **Google Webmaster** account and add your website and also your **website sitemap** to your account. 
Google Bots will crawl your website again after that immediately.

Comment: @RiazKhan: If you get your answer, mark the correct answer and close the issue.